# Angular 7 - Remover/Atualizar objetos de uma lista e atualizar no DB (PrimeNG - Picklist)

Tags: primefaces, typescript, angular-7

Estou usando o picklist do PrimeNG, igual ao desse tutorial:
[picklist tutorial](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist)

Estou usando o evento onMoveToTarget e onMoveToSource para pegar as informações do objeto:

```html
<p-pickList [source]="listAnotherPermissoes" [target]="listPermissoesOfUser" 
              sourceHeader="Outras Permissoes" targetHeader="Permissoes do Usuario" 
              [responsive]="true" filterBy="nome_funcionalidade,nome_perfil,nome_componente" 
              dragdrop="true" 
              (onMoveToSource)="deletePermissaoOfUser($event)"
              sourceFilterPlaceholder="Formulário, componente ou funcionalidade" 
              targetFilterPlaceholder="Formulário, componente ou funcionalidade" 
              [sourceStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'400px'}">
      <ng-template let-up pTemplate="item">
          <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div>{{ up.nome_formulario }} - {{up.nome_componente}} - {{ up.nome_funcionalidade }}</div>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
  </p-pickList>
```

Dentro do component, como posso remover o item (que vem pelo evento) e atualizar a informação na página e no banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira.

Peguei as informações pelo $event, depois filtrei a informação que precisava e enviei pro backend fazer o resto do trabalho.

Dentro do componente fica assim, dois métodos, um para cada botão de adicionar:

```js
addPermissao(event) {
    event.items.forEach( x => {
      this.perfilPermissoesForm.patchValue({
        id_perfil: this.idPerfil,
        id_funcionalidade: x.id_funcionalidade,
        permissao: 0,
      });
    });
    this.perfilPermissoesService.create(this.perfilPermissoesForm.value).subscribe(
      (response) => {console.log(response); }
    );
  }

  removePermissao(event) {
    console.log(event.items);
    event.items.forEach( x => {
      this.perfilPermissoesForm.patchValue({
        id_perfil: this.idPerfil,
        id_funcionalidade: x.id_funcionalidade,
        id_perfil_permissao: x.id_perfil_permissao,
        permissao: 0,
      });
    });
    this.perfilPermissoesService.removePermissao(this.perfilPermissoesForm.value).subscribe(
      (response) => {console.log(response); }
    );
  }
```